# Application crashes when scrolling listview up or down if listAdapter is notified while scrolling and crashes after about 20 seconds without scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I have a Listview with a customListadapter. I am updating arraylist with new data  using handler which runs asynkTask every 6 seconds and then I am calling notifyDataSetChanged() on opPostExcute(). Data are shown  in listView and updated and everything is ok. But If I scroll listView up or down, application crashes.

These are global variables:

```
ListView lv1;
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
PostTask postTask =  new PostTask();
StockQuoteListAdapter stockQuoteListAdapter;
ArrayList<StockQuote> stocksList=new ArrayList<StockQuote>();
```

And this is the activity onCreate:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.indeces_fragment,container,false);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) result.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);

    lv1 = (ListView) result.findViewById(R.id.stocks_list);
    stockQuoteListAdapter = new StockQuoteListAdapter(result.getContext(), stocksList);
    lv1.setAdapter(stockQuoteListAdapter);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.orange, R.color.green, R.color.blue);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            //mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    });

    useHandler();
    return result;
}
```

And this is the Handler which runs the AsyncTask every 6 seconds:

```
 Handler mHandler;
public void useHandler() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);
}
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            try
            {
                new PostTask().execute();
                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 6000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
};
```

This is the AsyncTask:

```
 private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<StockQuote>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<StockQuote> doInBackground(Void... params) {
       stocksList.clear();
       ....some json parsing here
       return stocksList;
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<StockQuote> stocksList) {
        super.onPostExecute(stocksList);

        stockQuoteListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Am I doing something wrong since Im new to android.

Error:

```
   on: Invalid index 8, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at profestock.moe.org.swipewithtabs.Stocks.StockQuoteListAdapter.getView(StockQuoteListAdapter.java:58)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:662)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4991)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3418)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3801)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3632)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2399)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2092)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting a ConcurrentModificationException because you have two threads accessing `stocksList`. `doInBackground` is running on a separate thread, and is adding data to the list at the exact same time as your adapter is reading from it.

The solution is to not share the ArrayList. In `doInBackground`, you should probably create a new ArrayList that contains only the new data from your JSON. Then, in `onPostExecute` (which gets called on the main thread) call `stocksList.clear()` and add everything from the parameter `stocksList` (which you should probably rename to `result` to avoid confusion) to `this.stocksList` before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine without scrolling.  But now the app is crashing only if I scroll the listView. I am getting the error above.